# Google Video does not embed in IE

Tags: video

This google video embedded code does not work in ie. Just blank space.

```
 <embed id=VideoPlayback src=http://video.google.com/googleplayer.swf?docid=7406382850822714049&hl=en&fs=true style=width:400px;height:326px allowFullScreen=true allowScriptAccess=always type=application/x-shockwave-flash> </embed>
```

Chrome and FF works fine. The question is: How can I create Alt picture for embedded video(For example if the video is not loaded correctly, the picture with a link to the video will be shown.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO a simple link to the video link would solve.

```
<embed id=VideoPlayback src=http://video.google.com/googleplayer.swf?docid=7406382850822714049&hl=en&fs=true style=width:400px;height:326px allowFullScreen=true allowScriptAccess=always type=application/x-shockwave-flash> </embed>
Video not loading correctly? Click <a href="videourl">HERE</a>
```

By the way AFAIK Internet Explorer doesn't support embeddings.